# How do I change or turn off a css attribute using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tags, overriding

I am typically able to select an element using it's ID and manipulate it or via it's associated class, but I cannot do that with the current element as it's using a  tag which is taking precedence over my changes. Is there anyway to override the tag or turn off part of the CSS for that tag that applies to my element?

Below is the CSS element I am trying to edit
[image]

Below is the HTML 'div' I am trying to edit with the actual item highlighted in blue
[image]

Comment: It depends if that `style` attribute, you see in the inspector, comes from the markup or is due to some JS... For sure, there is no `width` in your CSS... Making your question unclear.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't see how you are trying to change the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations.

This is visually shown like so:

```css
div {
  color: #ffffff00;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.first {
  background-color: blue !important;
}


/* Even though these styles are declared after .first, 
  .first takes precedence because it uses the !important rule*/

.second {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Both classes are applied to this div: -->
<div class="first second"></div>
```

So for your rules to have greater precedence, you too will have to use the !important rule.
However:

> Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided

So be sure to never use !important unless it's the only option.

The following code should serve as a base for your question:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("example")
div.style.setProperty("background-color", "green", "important");
```

```css
div {
  color: #ffffff00;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.first {
  background-color: blue !important;
}


/* Even though these styles are declared after .first, 
      .first takes precedence because it uses the !important rule*/

.second {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" class="first second"></div>
```

Hope this helps, and have a good day!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I was able to use the following:
     document.getElementById('ext-gen91').style.setProperty("font-size", "12px", "important")

Answer (score 0):

With plain JS you can do, this works for sure, but is hacky.

```
let yourLabel = document.getElementById("yourID");
yourLabel.setAttribute ('style', 'font-size: 11px !important;');
```

This will override that "important!" attribute and is pure vanilla JS.

```js
let yourLabel = document.getElementById("yourID");
yourLabel.setAttribute ('style', 'font-size: 11px !important;');
```

```css
#yourID {
  
  font-size: 166px !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}
```

```html
<label id="yourID">label</label> not label
```

Run the snippet, this works fine now:_)

Comment: That doesn't work when I test it: https://jsbin.com/pezopoyuwi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I agree that this does not work effectively. It does something, but not what I was intending which was to turn off or reset the font-size attribute.

Comment: Weird worked for me in codepen, will update answer right away

Comment: @ptts thank you for making the modifications to the code. this would apply appropriately now. Your help is greatly appreciated.